# Whitespace is interrupting the flow of text inside divs

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a website.  In Chrome and Internet Explorer there is white space that interrupts the flow of text.  I don't know where they come from.

I need help finding them and deleting them.

You can view the full page here: http://printingunlimited.com/business-card-info.htm

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="about-product">
  <h3 itemprop="description">Business cards are often the first impression people get of your business. With Printing Unlimited you can make sure your business cards portray professionalism and uniquely position your business in your customers mind. Your business cards are printed on 14 point card stock with a gloss or matte finish with the standard size of 2" x 3.5". Business cards can include many options: rounded corners, custom shapes, and 14 point, 16 point, and recycled paper. If you have a design ready </h3>
  <img itemprop="image" src="example-business-card.png" alt="Business Card Examples" class="product-image"/> 
</div>
```

**The CSS that defines about-product handle:**

```
#about-product {padding: 0 0 20px 0; height: 200px;}
img.product-image {display:block; position:absolute; left:560px; top:-5px; }
#about-product h2 {float:left;}
#about-product h3{display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:5px; width:550px;}
```

**Image pointing out the problem area:**

[image: Screenshot]

Where does the white space between (`your business cards are printed`) and (`on 14 point card stock`) come from?

Comment: Please include code to [reproduce](http://sscce.org) the problem in the question, so that this question may be of use to future visitors after you've fixed and/or changed the linked site. (Note that you can edit the question at any time.)

Comment: If I could figure out that then I'd probably be able to fix the issue myself. Thanks for adding my photo though!

Also once the issue is solved I'll add the code that caused the issue to the post. That way the post won't become useless. 

I am something of a beginner and I really don't know what code is causing this issue specifically.

Comment: Remove from line 102 in `styles.css` `height: 200px;`

Comment: I checked your css,it's all messed up,it is not the way you should position each elements,you are using too much absolute,relative positions.

Comment: Try fixing the HTML errors too http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprintingunlimited.com%2Fbusiness-card-info.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @user2725919, next time, please format the question as I have edited it for you.  Had I not intervened and fixed up your post, you would have received 5 down votes and been completely ignored.  And then you would have to get a new login to get any more attention.  Read my profile below for some tips on how to gain reputation and get more of the help you just received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tweaking, this works:

```
#about-product {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  height: 180px;
}

#about-product h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.header-content {
  width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 190px;
  position: relative; /* <~ add this line */
}

ul#drop-nav {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute; /* <~ change this line */
  top: 170px; /* <~ change this line */
}
```

Comment: P.S. In Chrome you can `Ctrl`+click an element, then select 'Inspect element' to open developer tools, which is useful when debugging issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you should be using to solve these errors yourself is divide and conquer, as follows:

1. Remove all the html attributes and CSS styling that affects that particular HTML element.
2. Add back the html elements, in chunks, testing as you go, to see how each addition affects the page.
3. When you find the problem appear, cut the last batch of changes you made in half, to isolate which style is causing the problem.
4. When you locate the CSS attribute interrupting your flow of text, remove it or try something different.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so as people have already suggested, your CSS styling is not suitable for IE and chrome. First, you must validate it at W3.

Next, i have added some styling to it to correct it .

Here they are  :

```
<div id="about-product" style="height: 175px">
<h3 itemprop="description" style="display:inline-block;float: left;position: absolute;">Business cards are often the first impression people get of your business. With Printing Unlimited you can make sure your business cards portray professionalism and uniquely position your business in your customers mind. Your business cards are printed on 14 point card stock with a gloss or matte finish with the standard size of 2" x 3.5". Business cards can include many options: rounded corners, custom shapes, and 14 point, 16 point, and recycled paper. If you have a design ready </h3>
<img itemprop="image" src="example-business-card.png" alt="Business Card Examples" class="product-image"> </div>
```

The screen shot is here below:

[image]